# ssh git pull or push is slow compared to ssl pull/push

Tags: linux, git, ssh, gitlab

Git pull/push over ssh is very slow when compared to ssl. Anybody experienced that? Speed over SSL is atleast 5 times faster.

Did a clone using both the authentication and SSL finished within 1 min and new clone over ssh took 5 mins.

No load on the server and client during clone.

I tried to google and found [one](http://darrell.mozingo.net/2011/09/29/painfully-slow-clone-speeds-with-msysgit-gitextensions/), but this didn't fix the issue.

Git

```
$ git --version
  git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0
```

OpenSSL

```
$ Openssl version
  OpenSSL 0.9.8zb 6 Aug 2014
```

Comment: Your linked article mentions cygwin and your tags mention linux. So what is your platform you are trying on? On windows, openssh has several problems that were not yet completely solved.

Comment: @ Jakuje, Windows clients are facing this problem.

Comment: I guess it would be helpful to post version of ssh, git and so to understand it well. Problem is, that on windows, SSH is currently unable to multiplex connection to server and old git version are not using it or using some ugly hacks that make it "somehow work". All of it makes it slower than any other, more native method. Not sure if this answer would be enough, but maybe I can elaborate more tomorrow.

Comment: @Jakuje, Updated in the original thread...

Comment: I was interested particularly in the version of openssh.

Comment: @Jakuje, $ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1m 19 Mar 2015

Comment: I am facing opposite problem... git via ssl is much slower than via ssh